# JQuery: Target div with identical class name via how many children/descendents it has

Tags: jquery, dom

Using the following HTML and I need to target only carousels that have 4 or less items in them, ie the second one in this example:

```
    <div class="book_carousel">
        <h2 class="type_one">Carousel 1</h2>
        <a class="prev disabled">Previous Item</a>
        <div class="scrollable">
            <div class="items">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="http://www.place.com" class="thumb"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
                    <p>Info</p>
                    <a class="button" href="#">LOOK</a>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="http://www.place.com" class="thumb"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
                    <p>Info</p>
                    <a class="button" href="#">LOOK</a>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="http://www.place.com" class="thumb"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
                    <p>Info</p>
                    <a class="button" href="#">LOOK</a>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="http://www.place.com" class="thumb"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
                    <p>Info</p>
                    <a class="button" href="#">LOOK</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="next">Next Item</a>
    </div>
    <div class="book_carousel">
        <h2 class="type_one">Carousel 1</h2>
        <a class="prev disabled">Previous Item</a>
        <div class="scrollable">
            <div class="items">
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="http://www.place.com" class="thumb"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
                    <p>Info</p>
                    <a class="button" href="#">LOOK</a>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="http://www.place.com" class="thumb"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
                    <p>Info</p>
                    <a class="button" href="#">LOOK</a>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="http://www.place.com" class="thumb"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
                    <p>Info</p>
                    <a class="button" href="#">LOOK</a>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="http://www.place.com" class="thumb"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
                    <p>Info</p>
                    <a class="button" href="#">LOOK</a>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <a href="http://www.place.com" class="thumb"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
                    <p>Info</p>
                    <a class="button" href="#">LOOK</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="next">Next Item</a>
    </div>
```

Once I've got a hold of the div with four or less items in it, the idea is that I'll turn off the carousel as it wouldn't be neccessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

filter out the `.book_carousel` that has 4 or less `div.item` and do something. filter will return the carousel divs with less than or equal to 4 `.items` in it.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pZ5C5/)

```
$('.book_carousel').filter(function(){
       return $(this).find('div.item').length <= 4;
}).hide(); // Do hide or remove or something with them.
```